# Weird fortran numeric behavior when comparing to a constant

Tags: if-statement, fortran, real-datatype

So I have this code in Fortran:

```
REAL*8 DELTA,XI,SO,S
SO=0.273333328465621
S=0.323333333556851
XI=0.01
DELTA =SO-S                ! DELTA = -0.0500000050912297
IF(DELTA.GE.0.0)XI=XI/10
```

This code with those values always end up evaluating the IF as true and executes the XI division (i.e. XI=0.001 after. I think this is a weird behavior, but my job is to replicate that behavior in C#.

Compiled with intel fortran, no optimizations and and full debug information as part of a 32 bit DLL

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: With both gfortran 4.8.3 and ifort 14.0.1.106, XI=0.01 at the end of this code.

Comment: Same here with gfortran 4.9.1... Voting to close as unable to reproduce.

Comment: So this might be a bug in the intel fortran?

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't execute the IF statement.  Both with gfortran and ifort.

```
program test_delta

double precision DELTA
DELTA = -0.0500001
IF (DELTA .GE. 0.0) then
    write (*, *) "IF-statement executed"
ENDIF

end program test_delta
```

One change is that I added the expected "then" to the IF statement.  Otherwise both compilers issued error messages.

Comment: Sorry, I was been inaccurate. I compiled with intel fortran. and the exact line is: IF(DELTA.GE>0.0)XI=XI/10    XI does get divided by 10 when DELTA, which is a REAL*8 is equal to -0.0500001

Comment: Edit your answer with the full example including variable initialization and printing.